# Trigger a Python script remotely and run it on the host machine

Tags: python, tkinter, ssh

I have a python script which uses Tkinter library to do screen grab of the image displayed on my secondary screen. The script works perfectly fine. When i try to run the script remotely using ssh (command below)

```
ssh pi@testing.com "python /home/display_capture.py"
```

I get the following error message:

> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

which is understandable because i'm running the script from a remote machine. What's the best way to trigger the script remote but execute on the machine?

Comment: Have you tried X11 forwarding when ssh'ed? Something like `ssh -X ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ssh -t pi@testing.com "DISPLAY=$DISPLAY python /home/display_capture.py"
```

The -t option tells ssh to allocate a pseudo-terminal, and the DISPLAY=$DISPLAY sets the remote DISPLAY environment variable to the value of the local DISPLAY environment variable.

You will need X11 forwarding enabled on the SSH server.

Comment: Why would you need the pseudo-terminal? You just need X11 forwarding. Use the `-X` option to `ssh` to enable it.